# Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to test cordova-plugin-fcm ,
but when I try to build the project I faced this error :

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

And my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }


    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

apply from: "phonegap-plugin-push/moi617347-push.gradle"
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/Mifon-barcodescanner.gradle"


def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0"

}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}


if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Comment: this. gradle after i remove the plugin cordova-plugin-fcm because the project break , it doesn't build so hope someone help me to solve this issue so i can use fcm push notifications

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First of all, this issue requires a lot of patience to resolve..

Check if you are using google-plus (native plugin) or ionic push native plugin in your app. If you use that, cordova-fcm plugin will directly conflict with the versions required by those.

If you are using firebase for sending push notifications, you need not use ionic push plugin since cordova-fcm is enough to handle notifications. Consider removing that.

Kindly have a look at - http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-sending-push-notifications-to-specific-devices-part-1/

Detailed and simple instructions are given in that link for achieving this.

Comment: i removed it but i notice that is still exist in package.json :
 {
      "id": "phonegap-plugin-push",
      "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push",
      "variables": {
        "SENDER_ID": "967066271504"
      }

Comment: and about the link i did the same , but unfortunately not working, I'm now trying to update google repository from sdk manager

Comment: now i have this error : 
Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.
you can see it at this link for more informations :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095467/cannot-add-task-processdebuggoogleservices-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-e