# Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to test firebase FCM plugin, but it seems to have a lot of errors,
after solved many of them, here what I'm 
trying to do: `ionic cordova build android`, I have this error:

my build.gradle of Android is:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

FCMPlugin.gradle :

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In FCM Gradle, comment the last line (below) that contains Googleservicesplugin
".\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm\your_app-FCMPlugin.gradle"

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' <---- COMMENT THIS LINE TOO, add to Root gradle file
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
//apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin <---- COMMENT THIS LINE
```