# Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'. in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am getting the following error when try to build / run the Ionic2 application.

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.

I have found similar question  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080323/execution-failed-for-task-processdebuggoogleservices` but it didn't solve my problem.

Please help me to fix this error

Comment: Please refer this link https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/274

Answer (score 0):

@Anand,

Try to remove the android platform and add the latest version by the following command.

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

Let me know if it solved your problem.